# Como aumentar altura conforme scroll desce a página mas não diminuir com scroll subindo?

Tags: jquery, css

Estou em um projeto de página única, e preciso de uma div que aumente conforme eu desço a página, porém ao subir ela não pode diminuir, tem de ficar parada, do tamanho que estava até descer novamente.
Estou usando JQuery com o seguinte código:

o HTML:

```
<header></header>
<div id="content">
    <div id="broca">
    </div>
</div>
```

o CSS:

```
header, footer{
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    width:100%;
}
#content{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:1500px;
    background:blue;
}
#broca{
    width:50px;
    height:0;
    background:#000;
}
```

o JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var $broca = $('#broca');
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    $broca.height( st );
    if( st == 0 ) {
        $broca.hide();
    } else {
        $broca.show();
    }
}).scroll();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nzmdsm1/1/) de exemplo.

Comment: Olá Mauro, podes juntar o HTML (idealmente um jsFiddle) para a pergunta ficar mais completa?

Comment: Olá Sergio. Como você comentou, acrescentei um jsFiddle na postagem inicial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mauro, precisa apenas verificar se o `scroll` é maior que  `height` da `div`:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var $broca = $('#broca');
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > $broca.height()){
            $broca.height( st );
        }
        if( st == 0 ) {
            $broca.hide();
        } else {
            $broca.show();
        }
    }).scroll();
})
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nzmdsm1/5/)

Comment: Diego, esse exemplo que você alterou faz com que o #broca mantenha a altura enquanto dá scroll pra cima, mas ao mandar scroll pra baixo, logo de cara ele diminui a altura logo na primeira rolada. O ideal seria "esperar" até chegar na altura máxima anterior e continuar aumentando só a partir dai.

Comment: Alterei Mauro, vê se resolveu!

Comment: Resolveu perfeitamente, Diego. Muito obrigado.